# How to use shared preferences to have a one-time login in flutter?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I searched google/stackoverflow alot and tried but nothing worked. This is the flow i want:

1. User launches the app. Splash screen appears.
2. Login screen appears after splash screen. User logs in.
3. User kills(closes) the app.
4. When user relaunches the app, it should show the splash screen followed by the homepage, as user has already logged in once before.
5. User will only see login page if he/she logs out.

So far 1 and 2 works. But when user kills/closes the app and relaunches it again, instead of being directed to the home page, they are directed to the login page again.

The code for the splash screen:

```
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
@override

void initState() {
super.initState();
startTimer();}



@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Container(
      height: 150,
      width: 150,
      child: new SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/logo.png'
      ),
    ),
    ),
);
}
void startTimer() {
Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
  navigateUser(); //It will redirect  after 3 seconds
});
}
void navigateUser() async{
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var status = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn');
print(status);
if (status == true) {
  Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => HomePage());
} else {
  Navigator.pushReplacement(context,  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginScreen()));
}
}}
```

The code for the log out button:

```
void logoutUser() async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs?.clear();
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => SplashScreen()),
   
    ModalRoute.withName("/login"),
);
}
```

Sorry for the lengthy post, and really appreciate the help if someone could point out where i've gone wrong. Or if there's any other way to achieve a one-time login in flutter. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer is late now. But, If you are using FirebaseAuth, this will automatically cache your login, logout log. So you will not need to store it to pref. Just nee to make additional step when you lauch screen to check if user's last status was login or log out by the following. And this information can be used to rediret to the desired screen.

Code:

```
    Future<bool> checkIfAlreadySignedIn () async {
  late bool _isAlreadySignedIn;
  await FirebaseAuth.instance
      .authStateChanges()
      .listen((event) async {
    if (event == null) {
           print('Currentyl signed out');
      _isAlreadySignedIn = false;
    } else {
      _isAlreadySignedIn = true;
    }
  });
  return _isAlreadySignedIn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you set 'isLoggedIn' pref to true?

Comment: I dont think i set it to true anywhere.

Comment: do i set it as true in the splash screen?

Comment: You can do it when user logs in. If user can log in, you can control it when user click login button, set isLoggedIn to true.